# Outlook Reporting web service https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc throwing Unauthorized

Tags: authorization, office365, reporting, outlook-restapi

Trying to use reporting web service https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/ which was working earlier but now it is throwing unauthorised below is the screenshot for the same
[image]

Even after entering valid credentials API is throwing unauthorized error, azure app have requiredreporting permissions.
Please advice what is missing